# Suppose a massless particle is moving at the speed of light does that mean that the massless particle now gains mass? Not talking about photons here

Tags: special-relativity, particle-physics

I have a **massless** particle moving at the speed of light (the particle is not a photon). Will the particle gain mass according to the equation $E = mc^2$? How or why not?

Comment: Massless particles always move at the speed of light.

Answer (score 2):

It won't. The equation $E = mc^2$ holds only for particles at rest, and massless particles are never at rest. The more complete version reads
$$E^2 = m^2 c^4 + p^2 c^2,$$
where $p$ is the particle's momentum. For $m=0$, regardless of the specific particle (photon or something else), one has
$$E = pc,$$
which is perfectly fine.

Furthermore, it is worth mentioning that any massless particle will always be moving at the speed of light and relativity does not predict any mechanism that will lead the particle to gain mass.